I'm making a menu bar with tsx, but when I press the menu bar, the icon should be converted, but it won't. Which part is the problem?
"use client"
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faBars, faXmark } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";


export default function Navigation() {
    const [showSideBar, setShowSideBar] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const toggleNavbar = ():void => {
        setShowSideBar(!showSideBar)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <title>sweetieGN</title>
            <nav>
                <Image className="inline-block h-10 w-10 relative top-6 left-6 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="/title.jpeg" width={100} height={100} alt="" />
                <div className="flex justify-end relative -top-2 right-12">
                    <button className="text-2xl text-white" onClick={toggleNavbar}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={showSideBar ? faBars : faXmark} />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

}
First time I Googled and since then I haven't been able to find an answer and I've asked ai, but I haven't solved it.

Your code works fine. Is your button under an element, blocking it from being clicked on? Are there javascript errors?

Ah! I found out that the problem was caused by another element blocking the button, so adding a zIndex value to the button fixed the problem. Thanks!
